# Get string value from a byte string

Tags: c#

I have to get the value from byte string this is the byte string

4W3CfJ//nw1CpeA5NfXx9Ia32JyVmgpRrQCzUabFUvv0fqXYLVeNBT6XKjBehFNGtQ3Sng3Zucqu+RcXUzJ3KA==

now how can I get the value from it

Answer (score 6):

Its an Base64 Encoded string you will need to get back the UnEncoded string like this:

```
 byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String("your base 64 string==");

 originalString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into encoding, but it might be as simple as

YourString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( YourByteArrayString );

Answer (score 0):

If the byte array is an UTF encoded byte array it can be converted using

```
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding(); 
encoder.GetString(bytes);
```